# C++, how to use a subset of all types

Tags: c++, random, distribution

I'm writing a function which I want to accept a distribution as a parameter. Let's say the following:

```
#include<random>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());

void print_random(uniform_real_distribution<>& d) {
    cout << d(gen);
}
```

Now is there a way to generalise this code, *in a short way*, in C++ such that it would accept all distributions and distributions only (otherwise the compiler should complain)? **Edit:** To clarify, the solution should also be able to accept only a subset of all distributions (which would have to be pre-specified).

I would for example accept the ability to define a type as a collection of allowed types but it would be even better if there is already a type which has this property for distributions.

Comment: If you accept all distributions, you would have to ensure that the type is valid for the distribution, otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @remyabel What type? I thought all distributions can use a standard generator like `mt19937`.

Comment: What is your definition of "distributions only". In my mind anything that satisfies the implicit interface of a distribution _is a_ distribution.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I added that because I do not want to accept non-distribution types, if you accept all types you also accept distributions but that's not what I want. It would be fine if it accepts only types which satisfy the implicit interface of a distribution, e.g. something which accepts a random number generator and outputs a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such traits in standard library. You can just write something like

```
template<typename T>
struct is_distribution : public std::false_type {};
```

and specialize for each type, that is distribution

```
template<typename T>
struct is_distribution<std::uniform_int_distribution<T> > :
public std::true_type {};
```

Then just

```
template<typename Distr>
typename std::enable_if<is_distribution<Distr>::value>::type 
print_random(Distr& d)
{
    cout << d(gen);
}
```

Also, you can use something like concepts-lite (but with decltypes, since there is no this feature now), it can not work in some cases. In standard there are rules, that should any distribution follow (n3376 26.5.1.6/Table 118).

```
template<typename D>
constexpr auto is_distribution(D& d) ->
decltype(std::declval<typename D::result_type>(),
std::declval<typename D::param_type>(),
d.reset(), d.param(), d.param(std::declval<typename D::param_type>()), true);

template<typename D>
auto print_random(D& d) -> decltype(is_distribution(d), void())
{
}
```

If you want just check that type is callable with some generator and execution of this call returns result_type you can just simplify function

```
template<typename D>
auto is_distribution(D& d) ->
decltype(std::is_same<typename D::result_type,
decltype(d(*static_cast<std::mt19937*>(0)))>::value);
```

all this things will be much simple, when concepts-lite will be available in standard.

Comment: except it would be d(gen) :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is very useful but rather ugly :( I would prefer a shorter/clearer way of achieving this.

Comment: @Haffi112 Yeah, C++ really isn't about being short and clear.

Answer (score 4):

I would just do:

```
template<typename Distribution>
void print_random(Distribution& d) {
    cout << d(gen);
}
```

Anything that doesn't satisfy the implicit interface for a distribution will not compile. i.e it must have an `operator()` that takes a generator as a parameter and returns a value.

Comment: This solution is more concise but it does not solve the problem of defining a type as a subset of allowed types.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood you question. You stated you want it to accept "all distributions". Do you want it to only accept _some_ distributions?

Comment: The code above is just an example of a use case. And yes, if you only want to accept some distributions this solution would not cover it.

Comment: Regarding accepting all distributions this code covers that case but it does not cover the "only distributions" case because it also compiles all types which accept a generator and return a value (and they are not necessarily distributions).

Comment: @Haffi112 name one thing that takes a generator, returns a value, and is **not** a distribution.

Comment: You could for example create a class which upon receiving a generator will output a string. This would not be desired. You could call this a distribution since it's just a constant string function but it would be preferred that the returned value is a number. In that case I would agree that it is a distribution but it is still more general than for example restricting oneself to the distributions available in <random>.

Answer (score 0):

First, some boilerplate to give us a SFINAE friendly invoke type test:

```
namespace invoke_details {
  template<class Sig,class=void> struct invoke {};
  template<class F, class...Args> struct invoke<
    F(Args...),
    void( decltype( std::declval<F>(Args...) ) )
  > {
    using type=decltype( std::declval<F>(Args...) );
  };
}
template<class Sig> using invoke=typename invoke_details::invoke<Sig>::type;
```

now `invoke< Foo(int, int) >` is the type you get when you take a variable of type `Foo` and invoke it with two `int`s, and it evaluates in a SFINAE friendly manner.

This is basically a SFINAE friendly `std::result_of`.

Next, some more pretty stuff.  `result_type` and `param_type` save on typing elsewhere:

```
template<class T>
using result_type = typename T::result_type;
template<class T>
using param_type = typename T::param_type;
```

`details::has_property< X, T >` will take a template `X` and apply `T`.  If this succeeds, it is `true_type`, otherwise `false_type`:

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class>class X, class T, class=void>
  struct has_property : std::false_type {};
  template<template<class>class X, class T>
  struct has_property<X,T,void(X<T>)> : std::true_type {};
}
```

This gives us `has_result_type` etc in a pretty way:

```
template<class T>
using has_result_type = details::has_property< result_type, T >;
template<class T>
using has_param_type = details::has_property< param_type, T >;
template<class Sig>
using can_invoke = details::has_property< invoke, Sig >;
template<class T>
using can_twist_invoke = can_invoke< T(std::mt19937) >;
```

I think the simplicity of these declarations is worth the earlier boilerplate.

Now, a bit of boolean metaprogramming:

```
template<bool...> struct all_of : std::true_type {};
template<bool b0, bool... bs> struct all_of : std::integral_constant< bool, b0 && all_of<bs...>{} > {};

template<class T, template<class>class... Tests>
using passes_tests = all_of< Tests<T>{}... >;
```

And we get our one line pretty `is_distribution`:

```
template<class T>
using is_distribution = passes_tests< T, has_result_type, has_param_type, can_twist_invoke >;
```

This does not yet cover `.param` or `.reset`.

This style leads to more code, but the "nasty" stuff gets hidden away in details namespaces.  Someone who sees `is_distribution` can look at the definition and see self-documented what it means.  Only after drilling down will they see the messier implementation details.